# Extjs getComponent from another view

Tags: extjs, mvvm, combobox

(Snapshoots are [here](https://unsee.cc/tarozemu/) for more details)
i got this : a combobox in the main view and 3 tabs that use the combobox to load their store.

The files `Mathrice*.js` describe the whole view and the others (in directories) are the tabs. 
My question is if there is a way to get the combobox in the tabs controller

Comment: Which version of Ext are you currently using? 5 or 4?

Answer (score 0):

If your combobox has an ID as displayed below

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    id: 'mycombobox',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Then you can get the combobox component anywhere in the controller using:

```
var cb = Ext.getCmp("mycombobox")
//note the name is the id of the combobox
//here cb will be the combobox instance that you need.
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution :
Just need to to understand how viewModel works in sencha (cf [sencha doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/application_architecture/view_model_internals.html))

In *tab's controller*, i tried to get the **parent controller** which contains the **combobox** and then i play like i'm in that view.
Below the controller of one tabs

```
  ,mathrice : this.getViewModel().getParent().getView().getController()
  ,init:function  () {
        console.log(" VPN Tab Controller");
        var me=this
        ,selectALab = me.mathrice.lookupReference('comboboxLab')
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the combo and tabs are under different controllers, there's no need for the tabs controller to be aware of the combo.  You want to have the combo's controller fire an event when the combo's change that you are interested in happens.  The tabs controller should listen to this event and take action.  This approach reduces coupling and makes your app more maintainable.